# c++ How to split string into two strings based on the last '.'

Tags: c++, split, trim

I want to split the string into two separate strings based on the last `'.'`
For example, `abc.text.sample.last` should become `abc.text.sample`.

I tried using `boost::split` but it gives output as follows:

```
abc
text
sample
last
```

Construction of string adding `'.'` again will not be good idea as sequence matters.
What will be the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string::find_last_of` will give you the position of the last dot character in your string, which you can then use to split the string accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, will use that

Answer (score 8):

Something as simple as `rfind` + `substr`

```
size_t pos = str.rfind("."); // or better str.rfind('.') as suggested by @DieterLücking
new_str = str.substr(0, pos);
```

Comment: `str.rfind('.');` a single character

Comment: This (as amended) is the right answer. `rfind('.')` is a better choice than `find_last_not_of`; the latter has to do some extra wheel spinning because it can search for multiple characters.

Answer (score 4):

Make use of function [std::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) and then [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the first '.' beginning from the right. Use `substr` to extract the substring.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution , assuming you can update original string.

1. Take char pointer, traverse from last.
2. Stop when first '.' found, replace it with '\0' null character.
3. Assign char pointer to that location.

now you have two strings.

```
char *second;
int length = string.length();
for(int i=length-1; i >= 0; i--){
 if(string[i]=='.'){
 string[i] = '\0';
 second = string[i+1];
 break;
 }
}
```

I have not included test cases like if '.' is at last, or any other.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use boost, you could try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>    
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
int main(){
  string mytext= "abc.text.sample.last";
  typedef split_iterator<string::iterator> string_split_iterator;
  for(string_split_iterator It=
        make_split_iterator(mytext, last_finder(".", is_iequal()));
        It!=string_split_iterator();
        ++It)
    {
      cout << copy_range<string>(*It) << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
abc.text.sample
last
```